# MvvmCross resolving IoC dependencies

Tags: xamarin, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I am trying to figure out the whole Mvvm way of declaring singletons and especially ones that have IoC dependencies tied to them. In my particular example I have a UserService that requires an IDatabase and an IMvxMessenger as an IoC dependency.

The IDatabase is platform specific so In my Droid.UI project I have resolved this using the following code:

```
var database = new Database(new SQLitePlatformAndroid(), Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db"));
database.Initialize();
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IDatabase>(database);
```

In my .Core project I have the following code:

```
var database = Mvx.Resolve<IDatabase>();
var messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserService>(new UserService(database, messenger));
```

I am trying to wrap my head around this. What really is the Mvx.Resolve's job and how it works along with the resolving other dependencies. I have already tested the code above and it doesn't seem to be working so I know I am missing something important here.

Any help on this will be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this link to the [Service Location and Inversion of Control](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc) page for MvvmCross and look at [Constructor Injection](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc#constructor-injection) and [Lazy Singleton](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc#lazy-singleton-registration).

Instead of resolving the dependency when you register the next, have it be resolved when the UserService instance gets initialized.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Can you give sample code? for both UI and Core

Comment: I think I need to read further into it. I was able to make it work by registering type. Which is great! but I still can't understand the reasons for each, so perhaps further reading will help. Thanks.